# как сделать так чтобы on_raw_reaction_add не реагировало на бота?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Написал такой код:

```py
@bot.command()
async def роль(ctx):
    await ctx.send("**`[✅ | Запрос отправлен] Запрос был успешно отправлен. Ожидайте проверку заявки модератором`**")
    channel = bot.get_channel(1043881287842275401)
    message = await channel.send("**`Была создана заявка на выдачу роли! Одобрить - ✅ | Отклонить - ❌ | Запросить доказательства - `**")
    await message.add_reaction('✅')
    await message.add_reaction('❌')
    await message.add_reaction('')


@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.channel_id == 1043881287842275401:
        if str(payload.emoji) == "✅":
            channel1 = bot.get_channel(1043881288504971269)
            await channel1.send(f"**`[✅ | Одобрение] модератор`** {payload.member.mention} **`одобрил ваш запрос на получение роли`**")
```

но, когда появляется сообщение с реакциями, `on_raw_reaction_add` начинает реагировать на реакцию бота, а не пользователя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте проверку на бота:

```
if payload.member.id == bot.user.id:
    return
```